# SQL Server 2016 TDE: Database encryption scan for 'DB_name' was aborted

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2016, tde

When I executed `Alter database <DB_Name> set encryption on;`, the error message such the subject was appeared in Error.log, and `encryption_state` has been kept `2 (Encryption in progress)`.
The DB has only few records because it is just test purpose.

Before execution encryption, DMK, Server certificate, DEK was created with no error.

Besides, I executed `Select * from msdb.dbo.suspect_pages;` to check if some data is corrupted, but no data was corrupted.

How should I do to complete database encryption?
I appreciate if you give some hint.
Thanks,

Comment: [Self solved]
1. Delete all certificate and master key
2. Restart the instanse
3. Create Key set newly.
4. Encryption again, then succeeded to encrypte.

[TIPS]
When TDE is enabled, compatibility should be '130'.
Otherwise, encryption scan will be aborted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Self solved] 
1. Delete all certificate and master key 
2. Restart the instans 
3. Create Key set newly. 
4. Encryption again
...then succeeded to encryption.

[TIPS] When TDE is enabled, compatibility should be '130'. Otherwise, encryption scan will be aborted...